# WiX4 bootstrapper: Use run time variable in conditional statement

Tags: wix, bundle, wix4

I would like to use a different *WIX* code depending on the passed command line argument.

```xml
<Bundle ... >
  <Variable Name="INSTALL_CONDITION" Value="0" Type="numeric" bal:Overridable="yes" />
  <?ifdef INSTALL_CONDITION?>
     <!-- behaviour #1 -->
  <?else?>
     <!-- behaviour #2 -->
  <?endif?>
```

In fact my variable `INSTALL_CONDITION` is not defined at the time of fulfillment of the condition, because all the time I am getting "behaviour #2"

**Expected scenario:**

```xml
  <?if INSTALL_CONDITION = 1?>
     <!-- behaviour #1 -->
  <?else?>
     <!-- behaviour #2 -->
  <?endif?>
```

**Launch command:**

```
.\MyBundle.exe /log log.txt  INSTALL_CONDITION=1
```

**A variable in logs:**

```
Initializing numeric variable 'INSTALL_CONDITION' to value '0'
Setting string variable 'INSTALL_CONDITION' to value '1'
Variable: INSTALL_CONDITION = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<?if?>` and `<?ifdef?>` are [preprocessor instructions](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/tools/preprocessor/). They are evaluated during compilation and have no effect at runtime. For runtime conditions, look for `Condition` attributes on, for example, `ExePackage`.

Comment: do you mean the attribute like `InstallCondition`?